# Android TextInputLayout color changes back to colorAccent

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I tried to change `TextInputLayout` by setting custom style for its edittext as you see below:

layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/pass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I faced 2 problems:

1.It works fine with activities but in fragments it has no change and the colors are as `colorAccent`.

2.Even in activities, after setting `.setErrorEnabled(false);` the edittext bottom color changes to `colorAccent`.

What is wrong? Is it a bug in android?

Comment: which AppCompat version do you use? it could be related to this Issue in AppCompat lower than v23 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=169760

Comment: @woley where should i check it?

Comment: If you are using AndroidStudio / Grade to built there should be a build.gradle file. In that file you probably have a line which says 'compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+" ' the number at the end is the version.

Comment: @woley no it is not there. I use appcompat but it is not in dependencies

Comment: thats kind of strange. did you check both build.gradle files in your project? like in this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/DyBJS.png

Comment: @woley I have AppComaptActivity class and just extends it in my activities. it is in `android.support.v7.app` package.

Comment: if you have a compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) in your gradle file the AppCompat library could be in a libs folder in your project.

Comment: @woley I have some jars there but not appcompat

Comment: could you post the dependency section of your gradle files? pretty hard to tell where your appcompat comes from :/

Comment: @woley I use `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

Comment: sry my mistake! the support:design lib will fetch the appcompat-v7 and support-v4 for you in the corresponding versions. (23.1.0)

Comment: so the problem is not with library?

Comment: There was an issue in 23.1.0 with the setErrorEnabled(false) you've mentioned - so you can try to bump it up to 23.1.1see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=184457